# Wants to fire an event after 10 days

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Wants fire an event after 10 days, Let's say I have an expiry date to show image saved in my app folder. I am saving download time of asset and I want to check that time with 10 days after downloaded time. If that crosses 10 days that asset should remove automatically from app folder.

I know some of the options we have like:

**1. GCD:**

```
int parameter1 = 12;
float parameter2 = 144.1;

// Delay execution of my block for 10 seconds.
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"parameter1: %d parameter2: %f", parameter1, parameter2);
});
```

**2. Local Notifications/EventKit:**

Note: it shouldn't throw any alert, It should delete asset in the background from app folder.

Is there any way to trigger the method with duration.

Comment: Executing this every 10 second could be very expensive over the period of time. Do you want this to be fired exactly after 10 days which is 864000 seconds after it downloaded or is it enough to expire it at the end of the day of a certain day ?

Comment: it's 10 days, let's say 10 assets download and saved into a local folder, Need to check that 10 assets every time and delete from cache folder.

Comment: I think you can check it only when the application wakes up  from suspended mode (didBecomeActive notification)

Comment: we have some corner scenarios like youtube. Once you offline assets, you're in the same offline page, App didn't go to other screen or background from 10 days just imagine. That asset expires automatically in youtube same functionality we need to implement.

Comment: what I suggest you to do is to right a background service to handle the deletion at a certain time of the day or whenever app start up. But if want to expire the asset after exact 240hours so lets say asset downloaded on 1.01 on 1st and you want it to expire on 1.01 in 10th then you will have to have different approach.

Comment: Is there any reason to delete the content, if your app is in background (or terminated)? Or is it okay for you, if it is done only, when the app wakes up and is running in foreground?

Comment: Let say one expiry has permission to 4 days and another one has 10 days, it's based on user specific and. we will get download time and expiry time for the asset. If you download Multiple assets, you have different expiry dates for each asset. Let say 4 hours one asset has an expiry and another has one 1 day, Let's app running foreground and expiry time came for that asset how can we trigger different times for different assets.

Answer (score 1):

I keep the date that the file was added on the device in `NSUserDefaults`.

Then when AppDelegate's `application(_, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` would fire I would check if 10 days have passed from the last purge. If true I would purge again, if false I would not do anything.